# Transpose pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I convert a list of lists to a panda dataframe?

it is not in the form of coloumns but instead in the form of rows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from random import randrange
import pandas

data = [[[randrange(0,100) for j in range(0, 12)] for y in range(0, 12)] for x in range(0, 5)]
print data
df = pandas.DataFrame(data[0], columns=['B','P','F','I','FP','BP','2','M','3','1','I','L'])
print df
```

for example:

```
data[0][0] == [64, 73, 76, 64, 61, 32, 36, 94, 81, 49, 94, 48]
```

I want it to be shown as rows and not coloumns.

currently it shows somethign like this

```
     B   P   F   I  FP  BP   2   M   3   1   I   L
0   64  73  76  64  61  32  36  94  81  49  94  48
1   57  58  69  46  34  66  15  24  20  49  25  98
2   99  61  73  69  21  33  78  31  16  11  77  71
3   41   1  55  34  97  64  98   9  42  77  95  41
4   36  50  54  27  74   0   8  59  27  54   6  90
5   74  72  75  30  62  42  90  26  13  49  74   9
6   41  92  11  38  24  48  34  74  50  10  42   9
7   77   9  77  63  23   5  50  66  49   5  66  98
8   90  66  97  16  39  55  38   4  33  52  64   5
9   18  14  62  87  54  38  29  10  66  18  15  86
10  60  89  57  28  18  68  11  29  94  34  37  59
11  78  67  93  18  14  28  64  11  77  79  94  66
```

I want the rows and coloumns to be switched. Moreover, How do I make it for all 5 main lists?

This is how I want the output to look like with other coloumns also filled in.

```
     B   P   F   I  FP  BP   2   M   3   1   I   L
0    64 
1    73  
1    76  
2    64  
3    61  
4    32  
5    36  
6    94  
7    81  
8    49  
9    94  
10   48
```

However. `df.transpose()` won't help.

Comment: transpose() doesn't seem to be helping. neither does reindex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy

df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.asarray(data[x]).T.tolist(),
                      columns=['B','P','F','I','FP','BP','2','M','3','1','I','L'])
```

Comment: Same idea, but maybe a little cleaner written as `df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.values.T, columns=df.columns)`?

Comment: But how will you do it for list of lists?

Comment: Do you want to process all 5?:  for x in range(len(data)): df=...   append each to a list, or whatever you wanna do with it

Comment: Where is the syntax `df.T` documented? I can only find this page: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

Comment: Works here. Original (needs transpose): `x = pd.DataFrame([a,b,c,d])`. Fixed: `x = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray([a,b,c,d]).T.tolist())`.

Answer (score 7):

This is what I came up with

```
data = [[[randrange(0,100) for j in range(0, 12)] for y in range(0, 12)] for x in range(0, 5)]
print data
df = pandas.DataFrame(data[0], columns=['B','P','F','I','FP','BP','2','M','3','1','I','L'])
print df
df1 = df.transpose()
df1.columns = ['B','P','F','I','FP','BP','2','M','3','1','I','L']
print df1
```