# Write Pandas Series Vertically using to_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a loop running that has a long series that needs to be printed vertically to a csv on each iteration.  Using the to_csv is just printing it horizontally. Is there a specific way this needs be done?

```
Index        Value

 Age           25       
 Siblings      0
 Area Code     416
 ...etc

 Age           23       
 Siblings      2
 Area Code     401
 ...etc
```

This is an example of my series, I would like to have it output to a csv like this.  So I'm trying to print the indexes as columns and the values below it.

```
  age                siblings             Area Code
  25                   0                    416
  23                   2                    401
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? A [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be helpful..

Comment: I put up a quick example

Comment: can you add your code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried transposing the df and then outputting it?

```
dfT = df.T 
dfT.to_csv('Vert.csv')
```

Something like that might give you what you want. 
Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412510/transpose-pandas-dataframe).

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
idx = s.index.unique()
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(idx, [s[i].tolist() for i in idx])))
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

Comment: This still doesn't print it vertically

Comment: What do you mean? It gives the output you desire. Well, it will only work if your index really contains `Age`, `Siblings` and `Area Code` over and over again...

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I didn't test my code. `unstack` seems to reduce it to a Series again. Wait a bit...